# How to pull Facebook Page feed onto my website with out using the ifame plugin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am still new to development and have never used the Facebook API. I would like to pull a Facebook page's status feed on to my website without using the "iframe" plugin. I have access to this Facebook page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research i have managed to pull a pages feed by following the following tutorial.

http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2011/php/adding-a-facebook-news-status-feed-to-a-website/

Comment: its pure php can be used for anything