# Facebook RSS - Large Images

Tags: facebook, rss

It looks like facebook has again changed the urls for images.  I want to have a larger image than the thumbnails provided in the facebook RSS feed.  For awhile it was simple...I had code that would replace the _s.jpg at the end of the thumbnails with _n.jpg.  But then last spring or so that stopped working.  I fould that if i replaced the part of the url before the file name with a path like this https://scontent-b-ord.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t1.0-9/s720x720/ it would give me a 720px version of the photo.  Not as easy, but workable.

But it seems in the past couple days, the format for image paths has been completely changed.  In fact it not only seems that urls have changed, but they also require the corresponding code at the end of the file name (hash?) to be present to work.

Is there any other workable solution to get larger images in the facebook feeds?

Comment: Seemingly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601208/how-to-disable-secure-hash-for-images-via-rss?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you want, but:

Where I work we too were doing image URL rewrites to get larger versions of images in Facebook's RSS feeds. Because of the problem you're asking about, we ended up switching to using the FB Graph API to get our feeds (and images). We're getting larger images now, though the max size seems to be 480x480 and not a full 720x720.

To get your feeds through the FB Graph API you'll need to set up a Facebook app and get an access token for it. [This tutorial](http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2011/php/adding-a-facebook-news-status-feed-to-a-website/) (found through [this answer by eric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12638099/225292)) gives an overview of the process of pulling a (page) feed; [this tutorial](http://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/access-token/) (linked to from the first one) gives an in-depth, step-by-step walk through of setting up a Facebook app and getting an access token for it.

#### Note

The former tutorial gets a page's feed using a URL of the form:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/posts?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

At my company, we're using a feed URL of the form:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/YOUR_FEED_ID/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

#### Note

If you don't want to enter your app's info into the second tutorial's page to get the app's access token then you can generate it yourself by making a simple URL call, as outlined in [this answer by Avantaj Tvm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16412556/225292). Do note the security concerns about *using* the token in [the answer by CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12951233/225292).

When you get your access token in the form of:

```
access_token=YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

then you have to use that whole token (`YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`), not just the `YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN` part.

---

#### Edit

To get an even larger image you can do the following, [as given in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12160162/225292):

For Graph API feed items which have a `picture`, take the `object_id` and construct the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{OBJECT_ID}/picture
```

This is a direct download to the larger image.